# Getting the name of a class which has a meta class

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Suppose I define a class `A` with a meta class like this:

```
class Meta(type):
    pass

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

Then, when I try to access the name of class `A` I get the name of the meta class:

```
A.__class__.__name__
#  'Meta'
```

However, shouldn't it give me `A`, my defined class?

**Note:** I tried to use `A.__mro__[0].__name__` and it does give me `A`, but I am still confused why `A.__class__` gives me the meta class name. Does anyone has an explanation of this?

Comment: `a = A()` and `print(a.__class__.__name__)` ... `'A'` - `class P: pass` ... `print(P.__class__.__name__)` is `type` and `P` if you use the instance ... seems legit

Comment: Oh, yes that works. Is there a way to get the class name without instantiating it, and without using `__mro__`?

Comment: use `A.__name__` ?

Comment: Ahh.. Thats exactly what I was missing. Not sure how i missed that. Feel free to write this as the answer.

Comment: Because the *class of A* is the metaclass. So the *name* will be meta. A class object is an instance like any other, so just as if you did `a = A()` and `a.__class__.__name__` will give you `A`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__class__` dunder reports:

> the class to which a class instance belongs.

Quote from [`instance.__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__)

The `class A` belongs to the class of it's metaclass - only instances of `A` belong to the class `A` itself.

```
a = A() 
print(a.__class__.__name__) # 'A' 
print(A.__class__.__name__) # 'Meta'

class P: pass 

print(P.__class__.__name__) # type 
print(P().__class__.__name__) # P
```

To get the name of the class itself simply use

```
A.__name__
```

if you really need it.

---

I am still a way to groke all of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/7505395) to [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) - maybe it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is already the class - its name is under `A.__name__`. 
If you try `A.__class__.__name__` you will get to the class of which `A` is instance (that is, its metaclass), name.

`A.__mro__[0].__name__` will follow the "method resolution order" for the class A - the `__mro__` object is a tuple with all the class hyerarchy that starts in the defined class itself and ends in `object`. So, `A.__mro__[0]` will always be `A` itself - and `A.__mro__[0].__name__` is the same as `A.__name__`.

The `__name__` and `__qualname__` attributes are writable attributes: changing { `__qualname__` after the class is created will change the default `__repr__` for instances of that class, for example. Although they are in the language definition and "live" in slots in the class (not on it's dictionary), it is *possible* to create a `__name__` property (I mean, the built-in `property` object, or any other descriptor) on the metaclass that will dynamically change the `__name__` attribute of a class (but not `__qualname__` - this must be an attribute of the class, and must be a string)